# apply a script across a tree of subfolders

Tags: shell-script, rename

I need to apply the following script across a tree of subfolders but unsure how I should call this script so it is performed on every subfolder in the tree.  I only have to do it once.
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.*
do
    [[ -d "$file" || $file =~ _[[:digit:]]{3}\. ]] && continue
    echo -n "Considering $file: " >&2

    extn="${file/*.}"
    versions=()
    keep="$file"

    # Look at matching files
    for version in "${file%.$extn}"_???."$extn"
    do
        [[ -f "$version" ]] || continue

        # Save every one. Identify the current last
        versions+=($version)
        keep="$version"
        echo -n "$version " >&2
    done
    echo "==> keep $keep" >&2

    # Delete them all except the last
    for version in "${versions[@]}"
    do
        [[ "$version" != "$keep" ]] && echo rm -f "$version"
    done
    [[ "$keep" != "$file" ]] && echo mv "$keep" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a name to the above script, lets assume it is called `myrename`, and is located in directory `$HOME`. Then use execdir from find to walk the tree:

```
find /root/of/tree -depth -type d -execdir "$HOME/myrename" \{\} \;
```

Try with a myrename as:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "directory $1"
```

Comment: Tried that but I keep getting a       myrename: cannot open ./"Folder": Is a directory

Comment: You need to adapt your script to accept a directory as parameter 1.

Comment: Why give the script parameters at all? It doesn't seem to require it.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this run thu script in the _parent_ of each found directory?

Answer (score 0):

If the script has to be started in the directory it should work in, you'll have to `cd` there first. Something like this:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'cd -- "$1"; exec /path/to/script.sh' sh {} \;
```

(change the path to the script, obviously.)

Alternatively, you could modify the script to take a directory name as argument, this should be as simple as adding a `cd` to the start of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" ]; then
    cd -- "$1" || exit 1
fi
for file in *.*
...
```

Test if `$1` is empty at first, so that the default behaviour is still to work in the current directory (and not to accidentally call `cd` without arguments: it would go the user's `$HOME`).

And then just run a straightforward `find -exec` with the directory name as argument to the script:

```
find -type d -exec /path/to/script.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested by below method and its worked fine

```
find path  -depth -type d -exec sh /tmp/l.sh {} \;

/tmp/l.sh==> Its the script path
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Additionally, the `for file in *.*` in the script would access files in the folder from which you executed your `find` command.